# Azure DevOps - configuring two jobs in yaml, one with cron schedule, second with manual execution

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am configuring pipeline on Azure DevOps for running e2e tests.

I would like to have two options:

- tests will run automatically at some hour - using schedules for that
- running tests on demand

How can I achieve that? Tried such yaml, but I am receiving `Unexpected value 'schedules'` when trying to run manually:

```
jobs:
  - job: 'auto-run tests'
    displayName: E2E scheduled tests
    schedules:
      - cron: "0 5 * * 1,3,5"
        branches:
          include:
            - master
    steps:

<some auto-run tests job config here>

  - job: 'manually run tests'
    displayName: E2E manually run tests
    steps:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use condition to distinguish build reason:

```yaml
schedules:
- cron: "0 5 * * 1,3,5"
  displayName: E2E scheduled tests
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  always: true

jobs:
  - job: scheduled_run_tests
    condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')
    displayName: E2E scheduled run tests
    steps:
  - job: manually_run_tests
    condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual')
    displayName: E2E manually run tests
    steps:
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) you have list of build resons.